# How to call a function inside a for loop iterating in a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x

There is a function.

```
def person(sent):
    #body
    return chunk_sentence
```

There is a dataframe:code:

```
df = pd.Series(data)
df1=pd.DataFrame(df.tolist(),columns=['description'])
df1.head()
```

Dataframe:

```
           description
0   The arrest of Nissan Motor Co.'s chairman Carl...
1   The arrest of Nissan Motor Co.'s chairman Carl...
2   Get breaking national and world news, broadcas...
3   World News Tonight with David Muir full episod...
4   Get breaking national and world news, broadcas...
```

A for loop to iterate through the dataframe:

```
for column in df1:
    print(df1[column])
```

How to call the function that applies through every row in the dataframe?

Comment: have you checked pandas apply function. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: yes but didnt work

Comment: df1.apply(chunk_person(), axis=1) this is what i did and threw an error  - TypeError: chunk_person() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sent'

Answer (score 0):

you can use apply method of dataframe.

```
df1.apply(lambda x : chunk_person(x))
```